# Codes raises exception '[specific_method] is not defined'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got following javascript code. It's simply class, that should receive some data from REST WCF client.

```
class EmployeesWcfClient {
            constructor(url) {
                if (url == null) {
                    url = "http://localhost:35798/MyCompanyService.svc/";
                }
                this.url = url;
            }


            doGetRequest(relUrl) {
                return $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    contentType: 'json',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: this.url + relUrl,
                    async: false
                });
            }

            doPostRequest(relUrl, data) {
                return $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: this.url + relUrl,
                    async: false
                });
            }

            getEmployees() {
                return doGetRequest('Employees');
            }
        }
```

And I don't know why it's raises exception: 'doGetRequest is not defined'. Could someone help?

Comment: you cant create class in JS/JQ. if you try to create class `class EmployeesWcfClient` then compiler will create a function with same name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple:
Use this operator in 'return this.doGetRequest('Employees');'. In first code example the this operator was missing.

Answer (score -1):

inside ajax of doGetRequest the `this.url` will not refer to EmployeesWcfClient.url, instead it will point to the ajax options object itself. So take the reference of this before calling ajax request.

```
doGetRequest(relUrl) {
   var _this = this;
   return $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       contentType: 'json',
       dataType: 'json',
       url: _this.url + relUrl,
       async: false
   });
 }
```

But I am not sure returning this ajax function will exactly return you the response from the request though you made it `async: false`. Better use callbacks or promise.

Comment: If you are down-voting please comment the reason also